# Create a Translucent canvas for dropping files [PyQT]

Tags: python, user-interface, qt5, pyqt5

[Baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnPSZ.png)

[How I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8S7R.png)

Hi

I have a simple PyQT5 app. The main window is a QMainWindow which houses a QWidget. The Layout of the QWidget is as follows:

Class Canvas(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.ListOfPlots = []
    self.outFile = "temp.prb"
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):

    self.headLabel = QLabel("List of Plots:")
    self.label = QLabel("",self)

    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    self.createPushButtons()


    hbox = QHBoxLayout()                #Horizontal Layout
    #hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(self.combineButton)
    hbox.addWidget(self.openButton)
    hbox.addWidget(self.resetButton)

    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.headLabel)
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

    self.vbox.addLayout(hbox)                ## The horizontal box is placed into vertical layout

    self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

I want to create a translucent drop area as shown in the second picture with a label indicating drop files here. What would be the most suitable way to do it?

The entire widget is ok to allow drops. I just want a box indicating it is ok to drop here (like an indicator).

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic properties to trigger an indicator when it's okay to drop. If you need the background to be semi-transparent, use rgba for your widget's stylesheet background property. `background:rgba(255,255,255,90)`

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import  QWidget, QGridLayout, QFrame


class DropZone(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QFrame.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setObjectName('DropZone')
        self.setStyleSheet(
            'QFrame#DropZone[Dropindicator=true]{border:3px solid green;background:darkorange;}\nQFrame#DropZone{background:orange;}')

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            self.setProperty('Dropindicator',True)
            print(event.mimeData().text())
            self.setStyle(self.style())
            ...
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        if event.isAccepted():
            self.setProperty('Dropindicator',False)
        self.setStyle(self.style())


class Widget( QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        gl = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(gl)
        self.dz = DropZone()
        self.dz.setParent(self)
        gl.addWidget(self.dz)
        self.setLayout(gl)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```